# Redshift system view with S3 URI to manifest

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there any Redshift system view that shows manifest file used during COPY command?

I tried to find it in STL_LOAD_COMMITS, but it contains only file path. STL_FILE_SCAN is useful, but also did not help.

I can load link to manifest after dynamical building of COPY command in my Python script, but I would like to try to join it with Redshift system views. Manifest is always new for each COPY command and it would be a good candidate for the hashed key to join.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  I believe you will need to parse stl_querytext to extract the manifest file name.

Comment: The query text field in `STL_QUERYTEXT` has a *ton* of bugs.  I'm going to write a white paper specifically on how to pre-process the SQL you're looking for, so it can match the text which turns up in the table.

Comment: Found a workaround. My python script in Airflow dynamically builds COPY command. So, I log dynamically built manifest file to the manually created table with log info (manifest, load from etc.). I also log PID. That PID and timestamp helps me to connect it with STL_QUERY to filter by COPY and then with STL_LOAD_COMMITS